# Alarm Manager with Broadcast Receiver (Toast in Receiver is not showing)

Tags: android

What am I doing wrong here? I have setalarm and wakelock in manifest. Im a beginner with Alarm Manager

```
public class AlarmManagerActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_manager);
     }

   public void scheduleAlarm(View V)
   {

           Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);

           // create the object
           AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

           //set the alarm for particular time
           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

   }

}


public class AlarmReceiverActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
      {
          System.out.println("YO!");
              Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Triggered in ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

}
```

Please help me, My goal is to update my database with alarm manager every 6 in the morning. It's like reseting a value so I limit the users activity for 1 day

Answer (score 1):

I'll bet you forgot to register the BroadcastReceiver.  You need, either, to:

```
registerReceiver(new AlarmReceiverActivity(), filter);
```

or, probably better in your case, in the Manifest

```
<receiver android:name="your.package.AlarmReceiverActivity">
  <filter...
</receiver>
```